# How to check login status with React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I just learned how `react-redux` works. I currently have login, but I am not sure how to check if the user has logged in or not.

I created a backend with flask and used `axios` in the fronted to `POST` a request.

After I login, it just gives me a success status.

Now I want to apply this globally so that the navbar shows the username and can access its own page.

How can I use `react-redux` to check if the user has logged in?

What kind of action is needed and how do I have to create it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is up to your authentication logic but simply, you will create an action for login, then change your state according to this action. For example you can have an auth state in your store, then you can hold user and auth information there. After a successful login, your reducer handles the state change.

Wherever you need login info, you can check via auth state and render your components according to this. Of course either this component needs to be connected to your store or get some props from a container component which is connected to store. Also if you use React Router, you can have public or private routes depending on your auth state.

I have an example sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yk519xy7px

Here is a very simple code fragments from my example for this logic:

**action creator**

```
const userLogin = username => ({
  type: types.AUTH_LOGIN,
  username,
});

// mimicking an async API login endpoing
const fakeLoginRequest = username =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      username === "foo" ? resolve(username) : reject("No such user");
    }, 1000),
  );

// handling async login 
export const doLogin = username => async dispatch => {
  // incrementProgress is responsible for progress status.
  // Firing a spinner while fetching login info.
  dispatch(incrementProgress());
  try {
    const userResponse = await fakeLoginRequest(username);
    dispatch(userLogin(userResponse));
    // if successfull change our route to "dashboard"
    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  } finally {
    dispatch(decrementProgress());
  }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  username: "",
  isLoggedIn: false
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.AUTH_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.username,
        isLoggedIn: true
      };
    case types.AUTH_LOGOUT:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Example component part**

```
 render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    return (
        auth ? <div>Logged in</div> : <div>Not logged in</div>
    )
  }
```

You can connect this component to store or get this auth prop from a container. connect example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should create a reducer with some kind of initial state, probably something like

```
const initialLoginState = {
  userInformation: null,
};

export default function login(state = initialLoginState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_INFORMATION':
      return { ...state, userInformation: action.userInfo };
  }

  return state;
}
```

with the corresponding action

```
export const setUserInformation = (userInfo) => ({
  userInfo,
  type: 'SET_USER_INFORMATION',
});
```

Then, when you receive user information from your backend upon successful login, you dispatch `setUserInformation` to store the data in Redux. Then you can access it from anywhere through `Store.getState().login.userInformation` (assuming you've added the `login` reducer to your store through `combineReducers`, etc.

Also, I would look into how to use the [`connect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) HOC in the component(s) that are interested in accessing the value.